# How to list non-academic fellowship on resume

Tags: resume, united-states, research

I'm struggling to figure out how to list a fellowship on my resume, specifically whether I should list it under Professional Experience or create a new section for it near my Education section (or something else I haven't thought of yet).

I'm a researcher in the US, working for the government (so non-academia).  My work ends up being somewhere between more traditional research and data science.  Last year I got a data science fellowship through a large, pretty well know data science company.  This is my the only fellowship I've had inside or outside of academia, so it might look weird to have a fellowships section on my resume with only this one entry.  However, I work full time as a researcher, so listing the fellowship at the top of my Professional Experience section might detract from my full time job.  This is rather different from if I was getting a PhD and simultaneously doing a fellowship through the university - as that's a bit more common.

Comment: What makes a fellowship different from your standard internship? Do you have the fellowship at the same time as your full time job? How does this work? (Not in academia at all, so asking from ignorance here.)

Comment: @DavidK - It's a fellowship specifically for people who work in jobs similar to mine (research/data analysis bordering on data science).  So, yes I work my regular full time research job and work on my fellowship research on top of that.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure it matters so much.

If your current job take precedence, then place the fellowship alongside your education details, it's where people would expect a fellowship to be detailed anyway.

Don't forget that you can always change things around according to the needs of the role you're applying for.

Answer (score 3):

Tune your resume for your audience.

If you're applying for an academic position, put the fellowship into a section in or near your Education section (exactly where the hiring committee would expect to find it).

If you're applying for a position in industry, put it in with your work experience.

If you're applying for a government job, take the same approach - put the information in the portion of the resume *in which the interviewer would expect it*.

**There is nothing wrong with having multiple current versions of your resume, each organized differently to appeal to a different job market.**